# How to Reuse Mongo Db Connection Object in different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB connection object to different module. Problem is whenever my app.js run it should get instantiate then i can pass to other function of module.
Basically Mongo connection should be create only  1 time,

Currently i am using this code whenever we want to call MongoDb.How we can reuse MongoDb connection object outside of callback function.

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
     // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
     console.log("Database connection ready");
});

//let say here i want to use 
db.collection("cname").find({}) //but i am getting db as undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "false good idea" would be to use an other variable in the upper scope to store your db instance:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var dbInstance;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
     // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
     console.log("Database connection ready");
     dbInstance = db;
});
// Here I don't know if dbInstance is define or not -> big problem!
```

Still, if this looks like a good idea, it's not. It will give you an error about dbInstance being undefined. mongodb.MongoClient.connect is async, so you'll need to wait for the callback before using "dbInstance".
It's better to use functions to which you'll pass the db instance as a argument:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var myModule = require("myModule")
var useDbInstance = function useDbInstance(dbInstance) {    
    //let say here i want to use 
    dbInstance.collection("cname").find({});
    myModule(dbInstance)
        .doSomething();
};

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
     // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
     console.log("Database connection ready");
     useDbInstance(db);
});
```

Then you could wrap you code in Promises to have a better control over the async flow and avoid the "callback hell".

I hope this helps :)